# Java generics factory pattern

Tags: java, generics

I have a trouble with the factory pattern when using generics. I have this interface, generic on everything:

```
public interface Connection<T> {
    /* methods */
}
```

Obviously, I have this implementation:

```
public class ImplConnection<V> implements Connection<V> {
    /* body */
}
```

Then I have this factory, that must create an instance of a connection:

```
public class ConnectionFactory<V, C extends Connection<V>> {
    private final Class<V> contentType;
    private final Class<C> connectionType;

    public ConnectionFactory(Class<V> contentType, Class<C> connectionType) {
        this.contentType = contentType;
        this.connectionType = connectionType;
    }

    public C newConnection() {
        try {
            return connectionType.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to instantiate the connection at runtime using this (I'm using `Integer` as parameter for the generic type):

```
connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory<Integer, Connection<Integer>>(Integer.class, Connection.class);
```

but it says:

```
The constructor ConnectionFactory <Integer,Connection<Integer>>(Class<Integer>, Class<Connection>) is undefined.
```

Comment: It's a classic Java problem. Your constructor request a `Class<Connection`>, but you need a `Class<Connection<V> >`. Unfortunatly, you cannot have such a thing, for type erasure of generics.

Comment: You probably don't want to pass `Connection.class` since it's an interface, and you need to be able instantiate the given `connectionType` class. I suppose you will actually select the class at runtime using reflection, right? How do you load it?

Answer (score 4):

When passing class parameters, `Connection` doesn't extend `Connection<Integer>`. So `Class<Connection>` cannot be given as parameter to `Class<? extends Connection<Integer>>`. This is what is hidden behind your error.

What you should do if you want to keep this kind of pattern is to have somehting like this:

```
public class IntegerConnection implements Connection<Integer> {}
```

This will work.

However, and generally speaking, you know that you can create a generic instance without having to type anything special?

```
public class ConnectionFactory {
  public <T> Connection<T> newConnection() {
    return new ConnectionImpl<T>();
  }
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Connection<Integer> connection = connectionFactory.newInstance();
```

Comment: Yes, you can, but not a `Class<Connection>` to a `Class<? extends Connection<Integer>>`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, perhaps you could clarify that

Comment: I don't know the parameter type at compile time. I cannot declare a Connection<Integer> just because I need it to be generic. Integer is just an example. And at the same time I cannot put inside the factory the type of the implementation because I don't know it there.

Comment: You should probably explain what is the exact use case that you're trying to achieve, because this answers exactly to your question. You think you're going somewhere and are stuck in that way, but maybe you've taken the wrong way in the first place. So please explain what you want to achieve. This will totally change the question, so I suggest you create a new question with your actual use case. For reference, this is called a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

When I work with generics I often use Guava [`TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html). They are very helpful. Your class could be like this:

```
public class ConnectionFactory<V, C extends Connection<V>> {
    private final TypeToken<V> contentType;
    private final TypeToken<C> connectionType;

    public ConnectionFactory() {
        this.contentType = new TypeToken<V>(getClass()) {};
        this.connectionType = new TypeToken<C>(getClass()) {};
    }

    public C newConnection() {
        try {
            return (C) connectionType.getRawType().newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Take a try.

Comment: `ConnectionFactory` needs to be instantiated like this: `new ConnectionFactory<Integer, ImplConnection<Integer>>() {}`, right?

Comment: `TypeToken` doesn't have any `newInstance()` method.